# Limits and continuity at point c

Tags: real-analysis

Let f : D → R and define |f| : D → R by |f|(x) = |f(x)|. If |f| is continuous at c c, must f be continuous at c? Give an example.

Well, I dont even know where to begin. Would I just use the property that specifies if f is continuous at c if and only if for all \epsilon > 0 there exists a \delta > 0 such that |x−c| < \delta then |f(x)−f(c)| < \epsilon

Comment: try to come with a simple example when $|f|$ is positive constant, say $1$ (and hence continuous), yet $f$ takes values both $1$ and $-1$ near $c$

Comment: @mirko So if we take the value of 1, we can say that f is discontinous at c as it takes both values of 1 and -1?

Comment: yes, this is the idea, though you need to make it more precise, e.g. specify in some way for which $x$ we have $f(x)=1$ and for which $x$ we have $f(x)=-1$. So you need to partition the reals into two suitable sets, such that each contains a sequence converging to $c$.

Comment: @mirko so what would be the best way to construct the proof? I see the discontinuity but im having some trouble formulating the proof here,

Answer (score 0):

No. For $x\in \mathbb R$ let $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x)=-1$ if $x$ is irrational. Then $|f|$ is continuous because $|f|(x)=1$ for all $x.$ But $f$ is not continuous at any point.

A little more generally, take $S\subset \mathbb R$ such that $S$ has a limit point $c$ with $c\not \in S.$ Let $f(x)=1$ for $x\in S$ and $f(x)=-1$ for $x\not \in S.$ Then $|f|(x)=1$ for all $x,$ but $f$ is not continuous at $c.$